# blinking all led at a time in arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno, led

**  i want to turn on all 3 led'd at once then wait for sometimes(10 or 20 seceonds whatever) and then go off all 3 led;'s at a time **
*here is my code:*

```
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(12, HIGH); 
  digitalWrite(11, HIGH); // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);// turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

**but its not working.
so, how i can turn all led on at a time and of at a time???**

Comment: Why is not working?

Comment: @ Simone Cabrino maybe you didnt understand my question.
i want to turn all 3 led'd at once then wait for sometimes and then go off all 3 led;'s at a time

Comment: What you did is right, you are turning led quite in the same time if you do not count the milliseconds needed to turn them on. The setup seems to me strange. You are turning on only the built-in led (on Arduino uno id pin 13)... did you attached something to your board?

Comment: @ Simone Cabrino yes 
i conected 3 led's sequently in my breaboard then connected them with 1st one 13pin,then 12 no pin and  11 pin
but it blinking only one 13 pin led

Comment: Could you attach a photo of your schema?